# How to "Align" datasets with missing intervals

Tags: matlab

Let's say that I have two sets of data with intervals of 0.5 units apart within the range 0.0 - 3.0

```
Dataset 1:  x  |  y1         Dataset 2:  x  | y2
           ---------                    ---------       
            0.0   5                      0.0   2
            0.5   3                      0.5   6
            2.0   7                      1.0   9
            3.0   1                      2.5   1
                                         3.0   4
```

What is the most efficient way to align these data tables so that I can make a single table containing both Datasets and autofill the missing components?

Ideally my end result is something like this:

```
Dataset 3: x  |  y1  |  y2
          -----------------
          0.0    5      2
          0.5    3      6
          1.0    0      9
          1.5    0      0
          2.0    7      0
          2.5    0      1
          3.0    1      4
```

Comment: If possible you can try to map the x-vector to an index when you create it. This is easy since you can do all job with the x-vector and visualize the data with the plotted indices.

Comment: Just to let you know, it is suggested to use [table](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/table.html) instead of `dataset`, since it might be removed in a future release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you know what `x` looks like, you can simply create the output dataset and fill in the values for `y1` and `y2`

```
x = 0:0.5:3;
data3 = [x', zeros(length(x),2)];

%# "wherever x matches the first column of data1/2, copy the second column
data3(ismember(x,data1(:,1)),2) = data2(:,1);
data3(ismember(x,data2(:,1)),3) = data2(:,2);
```

Comment: It may be worth to be careful with the equality here (assuming the intervals can change, otherwise `round(x*2)` would do the trick just fine anyway.

Comment: Thank you for the response as this is the idea of what I am looking for. What about in the scenario that the datasets are of mixed interval values but still within the same range (tables updated above to reflect this)?

I have tried carrying out the function you have provided but get an error stating that the matrix is of unequal size.

Comment: @PatrickB.: indeed, that was a mistake on my side. I have fixed that now. Note that `ismember` assumes the x-arrays are sorted